# Import npm package in a .blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

I use laravel and vue js in a project that I am developing on. I have installed `vue-color` npm package in-order to load a colour picker.

npm package installed successfully. But when I try to import it to the blade it shows the error below.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

The below code will show how I used inside the blade.

```
@section
<div>
  .......
</div>    
@endsection
@push('script')
    <script>

        import Photoshop from 'vue-color';

        var manageDisplayStore = new Vue({
            el: '#containerMain',
            name: 'manageDisplayStore',
            components: {
                // Photoshop
            },
```

How can I import the package?

Comment: Do `import Photoshop from 'vue-color';` in your `resource/js/app.js`

Comment: Then what? just call it inside my blade file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import NPM packages in your `/resources/js/app.js`, then include `/resources/js/app.js` in your layout template and only then call it within a Blade template.

The `app.js` most probably has inclusions of NPM packages (like Bootstrap / Vue) if you've used one of the default presets when installed Laravel.

Assign the import to global variable something like `window.Photoshop  = require('vue-color');`

The `app.js` should be included in your layout by default as well.

Then use it in a Blade template like you've used. `Photoshop` or `window.Photoshop` variable should be available.

Check for the document being ready before usage or it could be `undefined` depending where you import the `app.js`.

Comment: Can you please provide examples?

Comment: Thank u soo much @Nikolai